# Is there a name for this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

I've seen in some books of Analysis the notation $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V), V) \cong \mathcal{L}_2(V)$ and I don't find anything about this vector space. What is it? Is there a name for it? Also, if I wrote this wrong, I aks for someone to correct me.

Comment: It's hard to say without context, as different authors use different notation. Presumably, if $V$ is a vector space, and if $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the space of linear maps from $V$ into itself, then $\mathcal{L}_2(V)$ would be the space of linear maps from $\mathcal{L}(V)$ into $V$ no? But again, without more details it could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think it's the other way round. $\mathcal{L}(V, \mathcal{L}(V, W)) \cong \mathcal{L}_2(V, W)$ for two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is meant to say that the LHS, the space of linear maps mapping elements of $V$ to linear maps $V \to W$, can be identified with the RHS, the space of bilinear maps $V \times V \to W$.
This is not that unexpected: consider a bilinear map $F : (u, v) \in V \times V \mapsto F(u,v) \in W$. Then we can choose to either view it as is, i.e. as a simple bilinear map, or we can look at the set of maps $$F(u, \cdot) : v \in V \mapsto F(u, v) \in W$$ for $u \in V$, and notice that $F$ being bilinear implies that the assignment $u \mapsto F(u, \cdot)$ is itself linear, hence:
$$(u \in V \mapsto (v \in V \mapsto F(u,v) \in W)) \in \mathcal{L}(V, \mathcal{L}(V, W))$$
Moreover, it shouldn't be too hard to see that the other direction can be dealt with in the same type of way, taking a linear map $G : u \mapsto G(u) : V \to W$ and "making" it a bilinear map.

When $V = W$, this indeed gives $\mathcal{L}(V, \mathcal{L}(V)) \cong \mathcal{L}_2(V)$.

This is for example used in differential calculus in order to write successive differentials $d^k f$ of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ without having to deal with unpleasant notations, since that same type of identification by isomorphism can be generalised to $k$-linear maps.